# Как "выделить" селектор для работы в нем

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например на странице есть селектор `div#player1`, в нем находятся другие селекторы, которые нужно заменять пусть будет `div#player1 #sum`, `div#player1 #sum2`

Собственно вопрос, как "выбрать" селектор `div#player1`, чтобы в последующем я смог работать в нем, и заменить селектор который находится внутри него примерно вот так `$(this).children("#sum").text(data);` , потому что так как реализовано сейчас выглядит так себе: http://f1.s.qip.ru/GjeazU8k.png

Comment: А что за child() ? Вы, наверно, что-то перепутали, скорее всего так: children() , или я что-то упустил?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: @VladSpirin children, да. Сонный был когда вопрос создавал ) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

а если так:

```
var el = $('div#player1');
el.find("#sum").text(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#player').click(e => $(e.target).children('#sum').text(data))
```